# Uncaught (in promise) Error: An object could not be cloned in Electron

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron

I want to send my files from the directory from the main to the renderer. But before that, I was trying to check, if it really worked. Hence I console.log(files). But I got the Error
Can you please help me to solve this thing?
I know that sending non-serializable objects is not possible with electron
But I don't know how to implement it.

> Uncaught (in promise) Error: An object could not be cloned

**renderer.js**

```
function App() {
  
  useEffect(() => {

    window.electronAPI.handleFile((event, files) => {

      console.log(files)
    })




  })
  


  return (
    <div >

      <div>
        <button onClick={() => {
          const test = "From App"
          window.electronAPI.sendGetFile(test);
        }}>Hello</button>
</div>
</div>
)
}
```

**preload.js**

```
const { contextBridge, ipcRenderer } = require('electron')

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('electronAPI', {
    sendGetFile: (data) => ipcRenderer.send('send-getFile', data),
    handleFile: (files) => ipcRenderer.invoke('handle-file', files).then((filee) => {
        console.log(filee)
    })
})
```

**main.js**

```
 ipcMain.handle('send-getFile', async (event, data) => {
        const filee = () => {
            const directoryPath = '/home/xyz/Javascript/';
            //passsing directoryPath and callback function
            fs.readdir(directoryPath, function (err, files) {
                //handling error
                if (err) {
                    return console.log('Unable to scan directory: ' + err);
                }
                //listing all files using forEach
                files.forEach(function (file) {
                    // Do whatever you want to do with the file
                    console.log(file);
                    return file
                });
            });

        }
        //const filee = "shashank from main"
        console.log(data)
        mainWindow.webContents.send("handle-file", filee)

        //     const webContents = event.sender
        // const win = BrowserWindow.fromWebContents(webContents)
        // win.setTitle(args)

    })
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you pass a callback function to your preloaders `handleFile` function which then gets passed via ipc.

Note that all [arguments passed over ipc need to be cloned](https://www.electronjs.org/de/docs/latest/tutorial/ipc#object-serialization) via the [Structured clone algorithm](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Structured_clone_algorithm) which does not support cloning functions.

One option to maybe achieve what you were looking for would be to just use a single ipc call which returns the `filee` value through a promise like so:

**main.js**

```js
ipcMain.handle('send-getFile', async (event, data) => {
    const filee = () => { ... }
    return filee
})
```

**renderer.js**

```js
function App() {
  
  const handleFile = async (file) => {
    const filee = await window.electronAPI.sendGetFile(file)
    console.log(filee)
  }

  return (
        <button onClick={() => {
          const test = "From App"
          handleFile(test);
        }}>Hello</button>
  )
}
```